# Why can Typescript not figure out the type in my code?

Tags: typescript, narrowing

Why does the Typescript compiler complain about the following code?

```typescript
type Foo = {
  a: string
}

type Bar = {
  b: number
}

type Baz = Foo | Bar;

function f(x: Baz): number {
  if (x.a) { // property 'a' does not exist on type Bar!
    return 0;
  }

  if (x.b) { // property 'b' does not exist on type Foo!
    return 1;
  }

  return -1;
}
```

[Link to Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAsAKClAhgLigGdgAnASwDsBzLAXyy1EigCFdTk0scAjQygFcAtrwil6jTM2jsAXl3iIAPmw4BuKQDNBlAMbBycSlC0AKAB6F5ASgEixnDNijktUSwDpcN7i5ykEMCCpCYADJouDJg8ru5evL7OOAFBISYAjJE40bGBwaFQALRZkphAA)

Comment: [Related meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404944/is-there-a-canonical-question-for-user-defined-type-guards-in-typescript?noredirect=1#404944)

Comment: thanks for the comment, I was about to search for a duplicate _"Ahhh I've already seen this one a zillion time"_ :)

Comment: I know it's how TS works but it's a bit strange. Sure `x.a` does not exist on `Bar` but if you pass a `Bar` object then `x.a` is just `undefined` it doesn't break the code to do a falsy check so I think this should be allowed in this particular case

Comment: Ok, why have you asked the question and answered it yourself :P

Comment: @apokryfos maybe worth it's own question?

Comment: @user2369284 that's a pretty normal thing here (there's even an option when you ask a question to simultaneously answer it in the UI), see the linked meta question for more details.

Comment: @apokryfos see my updated answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Why the compiler can't (or won't) allow those property accesses

Consider the following cases mentioned on this [github thread linked in the comments by jcalz](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42775):

```typescript
interface Vec2 {
  x: number
  y: number
}

interface Vec3 {
  x: number
  y: number
  z: number
}

const m = { x: 0, y: 0, z: "hello world" };
const n: Vec2 = m; // N.B. structurally m qualifies as Vec2!
function f(x: Vec2 | Vec3) {
  if (x.z) return x.z.toFixed(2); // This fails if z is not a number!
}
f(n); // compiler must allow this call
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=19&pln=13&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGoQQJmQbwLABQyyAHgFzIgCuAtgEbSHECeF19jBAvoYaJLEQp0CAMy4mpNrQZRJrSjM7EAXtI5zuvAggD2IAM5hkNZAF5cU5AAYANMgV3ka5ACIAFhAA2X3cgDuulBeACauyFwA3IR6hsYgFCLYFjTRBDBUIAhgwPrIMAAU5GgY2AA+JWIAlBJEyMAwyEUAdCo1UBBgVFAgpM1gugBiwCQQIQWYVZHIAPQzyAAq7sAG+XDAXqsNzvWrILrGcIoaAISEPOkFNFOEQA)

Here the author of the code makes an unfortunate assumption that just because a property is *present and truthy* that it is a certain type. But this is *doubly* wrong: you could have a falsey value of the correct type (zero or NaN in this case) or a truthy value of a different type.
But there are subtler gotchas:

```typescript
type Message =
  { kind: "close" } |
  { kind: "data", payload: object }

function handle(m: Message) {
  switch (m.kind) {
    case "close":
      console.log("closing!");
      // forgot 'break;' here
    case "data":
      updateBankAccount(m.payload);
  }
}
```

This is a scenario where you'd *want* the compiler to complain about an unintended property access, not just silently propagate `undefined`. Catching this sort of thing is a big part of why we use static analysis in the first place.

The Typescript compiler is already a marvelous feat of engineering layering a static type system on top of not just a dynamic language but an *ultra*-dynamic language. What you're looking for here is called [*type narrowing*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html), where you take a value that could possibly be more than one type and then narrow it down to a specific type. The TS compiler supports (at least) five different idioms to achieve this:

1. The `instanceof` operator.
2. The `typeof` operator.
3. The `in` operator.
4. A [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).
5. A [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions).

Let's look at each in turn:

### instanceof

This one works well for user-defined classes:

```
class A {
  public a: number
  constructor () {
    this.a = 4;
  }
}

class B {
  public b: number
  constructor () {
    this.b = 5;
  }
}

type AB = A | B;
function abba(x: AB): number {
  if (x instanceof A) return x.a;
  if (x instanceof B) return x.b;
  return 0;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8CwAoa0AOBXARiAlsNGAFzQB2WAtjgKYBOq6wA9uRAC71bAcv3QAFAEpETdNA4ALfBAB0YaAF5oAFgDc4gL6odKVKEgwAQmLSZcBIjjKUaDca3ZcefASLMTJM+TmXQAVk1zPT1UDgBPDFo4UxV4AB9oY2CAMyxyXnw2YhwcMEEADzJYY2FbajoBZHN8VKFC6HxnMEzaFnrYUXpaDix6cmhChWD0OoamlraO5O7e-sHhnFHoHr6B6AAGYLD9FCA)

### typeof

This one works well for JS primitives (undefined, numbers, strings, booleans, etc).

```
type snumber = string | number;

function f(x: snumber): string {
  if (typeof x === 'number') {
    return x.toFixed(2); // strings don't have toFixed
  } else {
    return x.repeat(2);  // numbers don't have repeat
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAzgdgVwLYCMICcoF5bHQSzgHMoAfKRVDAbgFgAoBgMwTgGNh8B7OKJgCgAeALliU06AJSiYeQiQDeDKFHxMo-UJC7rB2LDgDk4jIclQl9FSvQRgCdL0EA6YFwBi+QRAAm-AEyS1FAA9CG4BMQwUD48hsBQABYAhgBu0G6e3j7KUAC+UBAANjDQltZQtvaOUC62kMnAAUEqYRTIEtGxcPFJadD1EI25eQyj9EA)

### in

This one works well for structurally typed objects:

```
type A = {
  a: number
}

type B = {
  b: string
}

type AB = A | B;

function f(x: AB): number {
  if ('a' in x) return x.a;
  if ('b' in x) return 5;
  return 0;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeBYAUFKBDAXFAdgK4C2ARhAE7oC+66okUAQgsupqXgM7AUCW+AOY06aBtBgtEcAD7MA3KIBmhfAGNgfAPb4oSgBQAPPJICUeImUpsMUPkqj6A5Fid3dh01AoRghCh4AdFiKtvaOTqRuAlCe3r7+ugCsoZg+fgFQAAyhtGhAA)

An astute reader will notice that this has the same problems as the first motivating example above, namely that the existence of a property on an object does not in any way guarantee the type. This was a pragmatic decision on the part of the TS team to allow an uncommon behavior for a simple opt-in idiom of *wanting* to get either the value or `undefined`, and much like a cast is an implicit promise that the programmer is taking responsibility for the possible outcome.

### User-defined type guards

This works well for just about anything, but is more verbose than the earlier options. This one is straight from the [TS Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
function isFish(pet: Fish | Bird): pet is Fish { // note the 'is'
  return (pet as Fish).swim !== undefined;
}

let pet = getSmallPet();

if (isFish(pet)) {
  pet.swim();
} else {
  pet.fly();
}
```

### Discriminated union

This works best when you have a bunch of very similar objects that differ only in the (statically knowable!) value of a single property:

```
type A = {
  a: string
  kind: 'is-an-a'
}

type B = {
  b: number
  kind: 'is-a-b'
}

type AB = A | B;

function f(x: AB): string {
  switch (x.kind) {
    case 'is-an-a': return x.a;
    case 'is-a-b':  return '' + x.b;
  }
}
```

Note that you will as I said need to make the discriminant (the `kind` property in this case) a statically knowable value, usually a string literal or a member of an enum. You can't use variables, because their values aren't known at compile-time.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeBYAUFKBDAXFAzsAE4CWAdgObqYDW5AJngOQn4C0WZHT6AvuulCQoAIQTJqUAEZ4yAVwC2UiEUl0yjKC3ZY2Unmn5pB4aDDGI4AH1EBuAWgBmcsgGNgJAPZkojgBQAHnjmAJR4hKSUEhgEAO4kwK4AFlCBAHTq9CHRmJiuWPjQ2hxcWEx4RBDAckQ+AWlY9jF5BUWsHHrlmJXVtVpMUADUUPVSTZhGRkA)

So in summary the Typescript compiler *can* figure it out, you just have to use an idiom it can statically verify instead of one that it can't, and it gives you a fair number of options.

Comment: Does this answer actually address the question "why does the Typescript compiler complain about the following code"? I was expecting an explanation about what happens in a union type where a property is not known to exist on all members, such as the discussion in [microsoft/TypeScript#42775](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42775), mentioning structural compatibility and open/extendible object types, and how this is behavior is intentional. I'd normally add my own answer, but I see this Q/A pair is intended to be "canonical", so, uh, what do we want to do here?

Comment: @jcalz I would suggest that you either edit my answer or add your own answer and I'll upvote it and put a link to it in mine? I'm open to ideas here, I just wanted a solid dupe target. I can also edit my own answer, but probably won't have time to do it today.

Comment: I'm happy to edit this answer (but yeah I might not get to it immediately either)

Comment: @jcalz done. Feel free to edit if anything is unclear or wrong.

Comment: Nice, thanks!  It's funny how `in` has technically the same issue as direct access (e.g., `if ("z" in x) return x.toFixed(2);` will *not* have a compiler error but could lead to the same runtime badness as `if (z.x)`) but they don't care.  [This comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42775#issuecomment-778419557) makes it clear that this disconnect is intentional because `in` is less likely to be done "accidentally", but it never sat right with me.

Comment: @jcalz FWIW I agree that making people type out a `typeof` check would be preferable, but with so many tradeoffs to consider I can't blame them for making some questionable calls for the sake of ergonomics.