# Type 'A | B' is not assignable to type 'A & B'

Tags: typescript, static-typing, union-types

Why does this code not compile?

```
type A = { n: number }
type B = { s: string }
type Thing = {
  a: A
  b: B
}
function update(obj: Thing, path: keyof Thing) {
  obj[path] = obj[path]
}
```

I would expect both sides of the assignment to have type `A | B` but the TypeScript compiler fails with:

```
error TS2322: Type 'A | B' is not assignable to type 'A & B'.
  Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'A & B'.
    Property 's' is missing in type 'A' but required in type 'B'.

10     obj[path] = obj[path]
       ~~~~~~~~~
```

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
function update<T extends Thing>(obj: T, path: keyof T) {
  obj[path] = obj[path]
}
```

Comment: This works but does not answer the question asked, which is why the compiler does not allow the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

When you access `obj[path]` it could either return an `A` or a `B`, and the compiler doesn't know which, and it (correctly) will not allow the assignment unless all constraints are satisfied:

```typescript
type key = keyof Thing;
const keys: key[] = ['a', 'b'];

const path = keys[Math.round(Math.random())];
const thing: Thing = {
    a: {
        n: 3
    },

    b: {
        s: 'hi'
    }
};

const result = thing[path]; // A | B, compiler can't know which!
```

So now if I use path to access a Thing, do I get an A or a B? The compiler can't know, and it can't narrow the type at the point of access. You and I know that it's the same thing, but the compiler cannot prove it. Same goes for the funarg.

If you use something statically knowable, the compiler allows the assignment:

```typescript
function update(obj: Thing) {
  obj.a = obj.a;
  obj['a'] = obj['a'];
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUB2AuNBXAtgIwgCcoBfAKFEigCEFkoBnTB4QgS1QHNSLxoAVABYduiJGShQAhphgSoeTNTLleVANYQQdTSAD2AMyhCRAbjIBjPahZRdTO1oDaAXTpOA5FI8AaKB7wPF3NLa1swKWBBHS0GJwBZSMEAOkI9LFQAEwAKRKjUqSy9HGyASlLg0JtgKCiRTBMuOnFJSRlkeVbWjCgAZk7SHzIBxQ6urocPYQ8B8hIQq2qoQggGLAAbGsQ6ricIqOCoAHoj2CgAHxo-KxwwNnWiKAtCjxr1VD0AdyhP4QtBACEwwMGQswDY1igWDAmUiEGyejwACsGsIuKUxlBEUjklI6NjcfJsZ5vG5EMSvEEVPIgA)

So that covers the *why*, but in case you want to know how to get the compiler to understand the correct type, check out [this canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66233215/3757232)

Comment: Thanks. I understand the `A | B` type but where does the `A & B` type come from?

Comment: @Tamlyn since the compiler doesn't know if it's an A or a B, in order to allow the assignment you have to satisfy the structural constraints of *both* types, hence A & B. You could for example assign `{n: 3, s: 'hi'}` and that works since that object qualifies. Interestingly (and I'm not sure why this is the case) that works with my answer but not nghiepit's. I may have to ask a separate question about that!

Comment: [Updated playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUB2AuNBXAtgIwgCcoBfAKFEigCEFkoBnTB4QgS1QHNSLxoAVABYduiJGShQAhphgSoeTNTLleVANYQQdTSAD2AMyhCRAbjIBjPahZRdTO1oDaAXTpOA5FI8AaKB7wPF3NLa1swKWBBHS0GJwBZSMEAOkI9LFQAEwAKRKjUqSy9HGyASlLg0JtgKCiRTBMuOnFJSRlkeVbWjCgAZk7SHzIBxQ6urocPYQ8B8hIQq2qoQggGLAAbGsQ6ricIqOCoAHoj2CgAHxo-KxwwNnWiKAtCjxr1VD0AdyhP4QtBACEwwMGQswDY1igWDAmUiEGyejwACsGsIuKUxlBEUjklI6NjcfJsZ5vG5EMSvEF5ItbHgpIRZAAyWhiAaSHq9IbjRiYKZsXzyeZE5F7JJkhT08yqEGoMEQ1BQmFwgBMAB5+FAIAAPYAQLIMYxozgAPgRyIafn2gkwukMxgxLSeYRqBj0enxIqtlUkNJqdIZsGZzTZaEwnJDk2mXNI5kkxK9dH9UvkQA)

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to [changes](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769) introduced in Typescript 3.5 to improve soundness of indexed access types.

> When an indexed access T[K] occurs on the source side of a type relationship, it resolves to a union type of the properties selected by T[K], but when it occurs on the target side of a type relationship, it now resolves to an intersection type of the properties selected by T[K]. Previously, the target side would resolve to a union type as well, which is unsound.

```ts
type A = { n: number }
type B = { s: string }
type Thing = { 
  a: A
  b: B
}

declare const thing: Thing

const key = 'a' as keyof Thing

let t = thing[key] // t has type A | B
t = { s: '' }      // we can `safely` assign it a value of type `B`
 
thing[key] = t     // and here things break
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w18KXW)

---

For a working example refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67886418/3388225).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an index signature which accepts any key, with the value being an intersection of `A & B`.

```
type A = { n: number }
type B = { s: string }
type AB = A & B;
type Thing = {
  [key: string]: AB;
}
function update(obj: Thing, path: keyof Thing) {
  obj[path].n = 0;
  obj[path].s = "hello";
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question asked, which is why the compiler does not allow the assignment. Also, this loses type information!