# Maintain object value types for each key when reassigning values

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
const obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 'foo',
};

for (const k of (Object.keys(obj) as (keyof typeof obj)[])) {
    obj[k] = obj[k];
}
```

TS Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDHMCGAXDAIwA02u8RA5AGYgjXkC+A3JpvQE4wAUokWAGs4tPgHkkAU2BQAdEKkBPCLwSIAlPgh9FSkGKhKADlINwkGgNoBdDVqy4LiK0Jupnrm+2ZA

I'm getting:

```
Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

`obj` has different value types for each key and I want to maintain the value type for each key. In other words, I want `obj.a` to remain `number` and `obj.b` to remain `string`. I'm assuming this error is occurring because TS expects the type of `obj[k]` to be `string | number`.

Is there a way to make TS maintain the correct value type for each key?

Comment: While not a strict duplicate (as far as I know) see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67886332/3757232) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66233215/3757232) for explanation and solutions. Remember too that in order to pull out a type from a collection the type must be *statically knowable*, and `obj` could have properties of multiple types at runtime.

Comment: why don't use `Object.assign`. Like this: `Object.assign(obj, {a:20});` Or `Object.assign(obj, {a:20, b:"another foo"});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way, using generics to get the key as a *type* `K` instead of as a runtime value `k`:

```
const obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 'foo',
};

function set<K extends keyof typeof obj>(k : K) {
    obj[k] = obj[k];
}

for (const k of (Object.keys(obj) as (keyof typeof obj)[])) {
    set(k);
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDHMCGAXDAIwA02u8RA5AGYgjXkC+A3JprQK5jBQCW4GBACmUADwBpGCIAeUEWAAmEGAGsRATxC0YUTQAcROuEgB8ACjUwikgJQYKOBIgDaagLqpTbz+2Yc9ABOMBagkLDWJhYA8kgifAB0GpoQFi4OeKpWWib6RiYZrh52Dli4wmJWdv5AA)