# Determine TypeScript type of a possibly empty array

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need to figure out the TypeScript `type` of data coming into my React component. The data could represent one of two things, cats or dogs:

`my-component.tsx`:

```ts
export const MyComponent = { props: {
  data: any; // I wish I could use the union type "Cat[] | Dog[]" here
}}: JSX.Element => {
  ...

  return (
    <ComponentNotModifiableByMe
      data={props.data}
      // If "Cat[] | Dog[]" is used above, TS says "Type 'Dog[]' is not assignable to type 'Cat[]'. ts(2322)"
      // If "any" is used above, this works okay, but defeats the purpose of TypeScript
      ...
    />
  );
}
```

`cat-stuff.tsx`:

```ts
export type Cat = {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
  address: string;
  birthday: string;
}
```

`dog-stuff.tsx`:

```ts
export type Dog = {
  bar: string;
  address: string;
  birthday: string;
}
```

There appear to be five ways to check what things are in TypeScript, based on [an existing SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66233215):

1. `instanceof`

   N/A, this checks against classes, but I have types
2. `typeof`

   N/A, this checks against primitive types, but I have custom TypeScript types
3. `in`

   This would probably work if I had `Cat | Dog`. But I have arrays, and it's valid in my app for `data` to be an empty array. So, I can't rely on checking the first element of `data`, because it might not exist.
4. user-defined type guard, AKA type predicates

   This seems the most promising, but as with #3, there might not be any actual data for me to check, so I don't know what I would put in an `isCat()` or `isDog()` function.
5. discriminated union

   N/A, there is no `kind` property or equivalent on my types that is a unique identifier; adding one could be a workaround, but it might not work anyways, for the same reason as #3 and #4 above.

How can I figure out the type of `data` in a way that works for empty arrays? Currently I'm manually passing an extra prop to `MyComponent` but that doesn't feel like good coding practice. If there's a React way around this problem (instead of a TypeScript way), that'd be fine too.

Comment: How about Cat[] | Dog[]

Comment: From where should the type be inferred if the array is empty? The extra prop seems unavoidable.

Comment: Why can't you simply type `data` as an union type? Either define it as `Cat[] | Dog[]` or `(Cat | Dog)[]`.

Comment: `ComponentNotModifiableByMe` only seems to accept cats. Do you have a conditional in your real code where you use another component if you have a dog?

Comment: @ShamPooSham fair question but there's no conditional. I can confirm `ComponentNotModifiableByMe` works with both `Cat`s and `Dog`s. It's just a generic list display widget. I'm guessing the TS compiler always chooses to say "[the second of the union types] is not assignable to [the first of the union types]" in this situation where it can't determine the type for itself. If I reverse the order, the error is reversed as well.

Comment: @GuerricP I'm new to TS and was hoping there was some kind of `getDeclaredType` function or operator I just wasn't aware of. Seems like it would be useful for teasing union types apart... but I guess it's not possible because TS information disappears by runtime?

Comment: Yes exactly @Anonica

Comment: Hmm, I see. What's the type definition of that component? In the case of the types you've shown us, Dog is a subtype of Cat, so you wouldn't normally get this error. But I assume your types are a bit more advanced

Answer (score 1):

If the array is empty there is no possible way to infer its type, so your extra prop is required.

You could write something like this:

```
export const MyComponent = { props: {
  data: Cat[] | Dog[],
  cats: boolean,
  dogs: boolean,
}}: JSX.Element => {

  // After calling this function in a if, data will be typed as Cat[]
  isArrayOfCats(data: Cat[] | Dog[]): data is Cat[] {
    return cats;
  }

  // After calling this function in a if, data will be typed as Dog[]
  isArrayOfDogs(data: Cat[] | Dog[]): data is Dog[] {
    return dogs;
  }

  return (
    <ComponentNotModifiableByMe
      data={props.data}
      // If "Cat[] | Dog[]" is used above, TS says "Type 'Dog[]' is not assignable to type 'Cat[]'. ts(2322)"
      // If "any" is used above, this works okay, but defeats the purpose of TypeScript
      ...
    />
  );
}
```