# Typescript union type does not throw error

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

So, type definitions:

```js
// type definitions

class GenericDto {
  public ids: string[] = [];
  public dateFrom: string | null = null;
  public dateTo: string | null = null;
}

class FleetInformationDto extends GenericDto { }
class VehicleInformationDto extends GenericDto { }

enum ReportQueueAction {
  GENERATE
}

enum ReportQueueType {
  VEHICLE_INFORMATION,
  FLEET_INFORMATION
}

type ReportQueue = {
  action: ReportQueueAction;
  type: ReportQueueType.FLEET_INFORMATION;
  dto: FleetInformationDto
} | {
  action: ReportQueueAction,
  type: ReportQueueType.VEHICLE_INFORMATION,
  dto: VehicleInformationDto;
}
```

and implementation:

```js
// implementation
const dto: FleetInformationDto = {
  ids: ["1", "2"],
  dateFrom: '2021-01-01',
  dateTo: '2021-02-01'
}

const queueData: ReportQueue = {
  action: ReportQueueAction.GENERATE,
  type: ReportQueueType.FLEET_INFORMATION,
  dto: dto
}

// ^ works as expected
```

but if we add "VehicleInformationDto" to type FLEET_INFORMATION it does not throw error

```js
const dto2: VehicleInformationDto = {
  ids: ["1", "2"],
  dateFrom: '2021-01-01',
  dateTo: '2021-02-01'
}

const queueData2: ReportQueue = {
  action: ReportQueueAction.GENERATE,
  type: ReportQueueType.FLEET_INFORMATION,
  dto: dto2 // <-- no error thrown here
}
```

well, what's the catch here? am i missing something?

The question: Why am I able to assign `VehicleInformationDto` to `dto` inside `queueData2` when typescript expects it to be `FleetInformationDto`?

Edit: OK, yeah, it's because they share the same properties, then, how could I add a check for that?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcE8AcFNQCawGYEsB2ryoPboM4BQhAxgDYCG++oA4rOrAE6okAi4OoA3oaKNACuAIzKtQqBPgBcofOBboA5gG0AuqAC8odQG4+AkWJKIK4WADEmOALaz5ipaAA+odILJktbj2X38hUXEEM1gAFRx7BQwnV3dPb3i-QgBfYnIqGgsyWFhwAEl0ZBwmGzNcdA4uWAAPc3QpOgZmViqeUDSM6lAANVgAC1YcwuLS8rw22vrG+kYWdk52tMIGQRtQACVYaBLwAEVBWEOAQRJsPB4DWgBRADlrjeOw69TiVfWtnaZ9w8OwmHgvH4PWuAAl8gBhAAy1wA+vlbhYAPIbACyT3ySNuABoDBYYdcwvDESj0WFMbdXoQoHBNttdgcjvBtEDQBQzhVZJ8Gb9YKdzuh-BAAVz6d9GX8AQA6fHXQnE5FojFYoUITiybK5ApFEplAVVVIuS78dkC0VfH5M-kVXH8Gmwc08pn-OBSkHg6FwhGKskU22IdW9AZDWAjXXjSqcfTLEASGzQHI2BjgCOkPDyAORUCavJhsb6xYsgySGQ6ABEAEYy9jQGWAExltT+kLmKy2WQAcjrAAY6xWALTdgdDjvN0IRTs9vuDuuDisdqkkdPgUAAR15bDMFEd4t53lZps5dItEr5HLwUpu90ez399p3lslrtl8u9pOVOIMaqz36psYAeqAADuJQANY0FQoC1HAZywAghCxsIggrqgyDAfAmQxLWfSDOQoY6vmFRVGWEBcPa2YEkSb5KuSWISCuCA4LANDoDgK7gP01hAVBTDWEw6TLpmdayDhIZ5nqRGFsaEhSLIKiVtWtYNk2X6hG2digF2vbDjpo6qeYE6aVOw6ziOi6CeuTKbimwnHk6hz7gYh54A+p7WheV4PE81x3iKdm7s60ovlRJI0X6X6Bt+dagLGAA8-b9m41S8SUECcTgQHoKA-TMLAqRAA)

Comment: What exactly is your question? Why `ReportQueueType.FLEET_INFORMATION` is assignable to `type` or why `dto2` is assignable to `dto`?

Comment: @MikeS. as you can see on playground link, typescript expects dto inside queueData2 to be FleetInformationDto, but when you assign a VehicleInformationDto type to it, it does not throw error. Why am I able to assign VehicleInformationDto when it expects FleetInformationDto?

Comment: Your playground link is sadly not showing me anything, but your problem is that `VehicleInformationDto` is assignable to `FleetInformationDto` because it has exactly the same properties.

Comment: Ah nvm, you just fixed it :)

Comment: To further what Mike S. said, Typescript is *structurally* typed, not *nominally* typed. `type A = { foo: number }` and `type B = { foo: number }` are the same type as far as Typescript is concerned. [See e.g. here for more info](https://medium.com/@thejameskyle/type-systems-structural-vs-nominal-typing-explained-56511dd969f4)

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it is the reason. In that case, is there any way to make typescript strictly check for typing differences?

Comment: Yes, you can add a unique property, [called a discriminant](https://medium.com/@ahsan.ayaz/understanding-discriminated-unions-in-typescript-1ccc0e053cf5), to each of your types in the union.

Comment: Not precisely a duplicate, but [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66233215/3757232) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66233214/why-can-typescript-not-figure-out-the-type-in-my-code) should help you.

Comment: @JaredSmith, Thank you. It all makes sense now. I completely missed structurally & nominally typings thing. Adding a discriminant to `-Dto` classes works for me. If you can convert your comments to an answer that summarises it all, i'd like to accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is [structurally typed, not nominally typed](https://medium.com/@thejameskyle/type-systems-structural-vs-nominal-typing-explained-56511dd969f4). This means that as far as Typescript is concerned these are the *same* type:

```js
class FleetInformationDto extends GenericDto { }
class VehicleInformationDto extends GenericDto { }
```

While I think this is absolutely the correct choice for adding static typing to a language like Javascript where objects are a grab-bag of properties, it can lead to some subtle gotchas:

```js
interface Vec2 {
  x: number
  y: number
}

interface Vec3 {
  x: number
  y: number
  z: number
}

const m = { x: 0, y: 0, z: "hello world" };
const n: Vec2 = m; // N.B. structurally m qualifies as Vec2!
function f(x: Vec2 | Vec3) {
  if (x.z) return x.z.toFixed(2); // This fails if z is not a number!
}
f(n); // compiler must allow this call
```

Here we're doing some graphics programming and have 2D and 3D vectors, but we have a problem: objects can have extra properties and still structurally qualify which leads to a problem in this union type (sound familiar?).

The answer in your particular case is to use a [discriminant](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) to easily distinguish the similar types in the union:

```js
interface FleetInformationDto extends GenericDto {
    // N.B., fleet is a literal *type*, not a string literal
    // *value*.
    kind: 'fleet'
}

interface VehicleInformationDto extends GenericDto {
    kind: 'vehicle'
}
```

Here I've used strings, but any unique compile-time constant (any primitive value or members of an `enum`) will do. Also, since you're not instantiating your classes and using them purely as types I've made them interfaces but the same principles apply.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcE8AcFNQCawGYEsB2ryoPboM4BQhAxgDYCG++oA4rOrAE6okAi4OoA3oaKNACuAIzKtQqBPgBcofOBboA5gG0AuqAC8odQG4+AkWJKIK4WADEmOALaz5ipaAA+odILJktbj2X38hUXEEM1gAFRx7BQwnV3dPb3i-QgBfYgxzJmQKEngLMlhYcABJdGQcJhszXHQOLlgAD3N0KToGZlY6ngMAawwEWQByZAKiwdT09Ezs3NAANVgAC1YC0vLK6rwuxubW+kYWdk5u-j6WoYA3JZXYcbTCBkEbUAAlWGgK8ABFQVhfgEESNg8Cc6ABRAByYJe-zCYImD3czzeHyY31+vzCMHgvH4czBAAligBhAAyYIA+sUIRYAPIvACysOKtIhABoDBZyWCwlSafSmWEWRCEVA4K93p8fn94NpcaAcsD0LIUVKMbBAUr-BBsSrJWjpZjsQA6Llgnl8umM5ms7UITiyfKFEplCpVJV1VIuUGKmp61HomWamoc-hi2D+tUyrFwY34olkynUq2C4WhxAO+bXciwNZuza1Tj6e4gCQ2aAFGwMcAF0h4eQZyKgJ1FPMbD3HOUGSQyHQAIgAjH22aA+wAmPtqdMhcxWWxDMcABjHA4AtIu1xvBtPQhEF8vN2P1wPt71+kMRs7T-cSPXwKAAI7qthmCiRg3q7zy314d+BgFAjUxq0JC0KwmC6bhn+hrhCaZoWsmAo2uyBj2k2aEIqWAB6oAAO4VD0NBUKAjRwECsAIIQpbCII96oMgeHwFQ+AxKOCzLDmbbujUdR9hAXDhs23K8oh1pCqyEj3ggOCwDQ6A4Pe4CLNYuEkUw1hMMQt4EFJnBjrI7E3FxBZdF2-A9rIKiDsOo4TlOqGhHOdigIMS4rsex6nvwM7hE2rkHuuR5bumZwDC5VwcQU15aXej7Pq++kSgGMFfgYP7KklUYAUqwGgTCcKQbqmUftGcHCZaSHiSh3mZmhY6gKWAA8q6rm49TqRUEDKTguHoKAizMLAqRAA)

And now you can clearly see the error that type 'fleet' is not assignable to type 'vehicle'.