# How to return concrete subclass instance instead of type of abstract class?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In a subclass `WorldDetail`, I defined objects of the page name and a concrete class name at `pages`.
In abstract class, I created `getPage` method to get an instance of the concrete class by specific name.
I couldn't invoke the specific method as `subFunc` that only on the subclass but shared the method between abstract class and subclass.

How could I invoke a specific method just only on subclass without creating that method as the abstract in the abstract class, or cast the instance to a concrete Class name?

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgCsA5gUwQG8AoBMhABwFcRkBLWBMAC2CgIF4EAKASgQ4A%20IqXJj2EKlAB2CAEQs2eACZyA3KLIBfYjuIo0GACJ4IwOsmz4EeAB4Q805RisESYsdVoMmrdgJ5%20IREPcgkpWTl2RXZVDTEdTxp6RjAaADEqaUYuPgFhd1CEcJl5AGUaBAAzLNg5TQQdPQgATwoCVxMoOgA3FQDCaTwAd0CALixcPC0EADIEVvaAeyrJ-A1iRY6pgHkQACsB0QBtAGs8FonIbukcAF0JzrxuvuVdYmJQa7hEA3QEADqSygyGUACE0G4GhQoEsHPB%20l9oD8EPhEPRIHxHrsDhskt5GGjXNwKFMAHLAAC2eCu0Dot14EwAktJIMBsngACptPAAHieLxUBQaYlgS1ZiAqIFcAQgzDoYAAdBiIMdSfgKdS7vEimKJUxKlwhqMpcTeDrQiVZGkQGoEAB6e0LHlrPANJofP4YIEg5QmMwWGz2RzOQHA0EQsBQsRLPpQbrKAhohAqvKFS2mCIhIpiOT%208yWKZyCb5iyuEXkRKV976cWQBCjI0jMO%200vIPgaPX19WcBuKolTbh50wF1xyc0Op1bV0AGgQ0jhCDb5a7S2QeGVSxwQ6MAFEwQBVADiviUcjnPcVMTwfF4xEdSDra43yC3O-3x9P7HPlCmV4ytS3naD4AMJLFQoLzousDAMgyAGiA1S1BAdDikAA)

Many thanks :bow:

```
abstract class Page {
    public share = () => {
        return "shared";
    }
}

class DetailPage extends Page {
    public share = () => {
        return "reshared";
    }
    public subFunc = () => {
        return "Sub func"
    }
}

type PageDerived = {new (): Page} & typeof Page;

type PageObj = {
  [key: string]: PageDerived
}

abstract class WorldBase {
    protected abstract get pages(): PageObj;

    public getPage(pageName: string): InstanceType<PageDerived> {
        const SubPage = this.pages[pageName];
        const sub = new SubPage();
        return sub; // type Page
    }
}

class WorldDetail extends WorldBase {
    override get pages() {
        return {
            "DetailPage": DetailPage
        }
    }
}

const w = new WorldDetail();
const page = w.getPage("DetailPage"); // type Page, not DetailPage
console.log("DEBUG share", page.share())
// console.log("DEBUG share", page.subFunc()); // Could not call sub function
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can Typescript not figure out the type in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66233214/why-can-typescript-not-figure-out-the-type-in-my-code)

Comment: @JaredSmith I’m sorry, but I seems not answer my question. Because the extended class is unknown, so I could not set a concrete type in the abstract class.

Comment: Possible approaches; you could make your abstract class *generic*, like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NdAMdm) shows.  Or you could change from an abstract class to a *class factory*, like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N71vPW) shows.  Do either of these work for you? If so I could write up an answer explaining it.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz OMG, your 2 options are so excellent. Could you please write out your 2 options in the answer to I could mark it as resolved? I really appreciate it :bow:

Comment: I will do so when I get a chance, probably tomorrow since it is close to my bedtime now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple possible approaches here (and maybe even more than I will list).

One way to proceed is to make `WorldBase` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type of the `list` property (or at least the type of its instances):

```
abstract class WorldBase<P extends Record<keyof P, Page>> {
    protected abstract get list(): { [K in keyof P]: new () => P[K] };

    public getPage<K extends keyof P>(pageName: K): P[K] {
        const SubPage = this.list[pageName];
        return new SubPage();
    }
}
```

Here `WorldBase<P>` takes a `list` of type `{[K in keyof P]: new()=>P[K]}`, a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) turning the object-of-instances type to an object-of-constructors type.

Then concrete subclasses can specify `P`, and things work:

```
class WorldDetail extends WorldBase<{ DetailPage: DetailPage }>{
    override get list() {
        return {
            "DetailPage": DetailPage
        }
    }
}

const w = new WorldDetail();
const page = w.getPage("DetailPage"); // DetailPage
console.log("DEBUG share", page.share())
console.log("DEBUG share", page.subFunc()); // okay
```

---

Another approach is to dispense with abstract classes, and make a *class factory* which takes a `list` input and produces one of your concrete specific class constructors.  So `WorldBase` doesn't exist anymore; instead you have `World()` which returns a class constructor:

```
function World<P extends Record<keyof P, Page>>(
  list: { [K in keyof P]: new () => P[K] }
) {
    return class World {
        public getPage<K extends keyof P>(pageName: K): P[K] {
            const SubPage = list[pageName];
            return new SubPage();
        }
    }
}
```

It's still generic, and the `list` property has the same type with regards to `P`, but now `list` is a variable in a closure.  And let's see it work:

```
class WorldDetail extends World({ DetailPage: DetailPage }) { }

const w = new WorldDetail();
const page = w.getPage("DetailPage"); // DetailPage
console.log("DEBUG share", page.share())
console.log("DEBUG share", page.subFunc()); // okay
```

---

Finally (for me, anyway), you could just have a single generic class named `World` that takes a `list` argument in its constructor.  So in the case where you don't need to add extra methods to subclasses, you can just use the base class:

```
class World<P extends Record<keyof P, Page>> {
    constructor(public list: { [K in keyof P]: new () => P[K] }) { }

    public getPage<K extends keyof P>(pageName: K): P[K] {
        const SubPage = this.list[pageName];
        return new SubPage();
    }
}
```

Still generic, same mapped type for `list`.  And here's how it's used:

```
const worldDetailList = {
    DetailPage: DetailPage
};


const w = new World(worldDetailList);
const page = w.getPage("DetailPage"); // DetailPage
console.log("DEBUG share", page.share())
console.log("DEBUG share", page.subFunc()); // okay
```

---

There you go... hopefully one of those will work for your use cases.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-ABRPYAVRQckUyksXz1GtKWk0a6gG637B3e8PJ7Ptkv4h+N6a4zvWcFyQTYHhAZ5aC8UBIFgBBkEachtmeKV6AWFhljYTg1mVQsGFpNJz1UUkclw-JTHNaxCIcO03A8RtnSw-xl2VFkLm+cJSJqVJ6lKTIOhImtegKCiSio8pqjrZJajSf9Wj47J-iLfNBmGMZWkmCS6Kdeg1OWbA+w2bZdhOH02OuW5MHuTlcS+BI-nUbVERDNEMSxF4uXxQkIBJfj9AlVFKVcbROOUl1DPdFCenw+pRyEJlTLZHhrO5XkfgNYUkFFcVJU46pmwoRVlTUbVdTSoUjUEsj+ktQqxxnSrPABBttMw3xwt2EsEr9Iy7HUENJ0jJcvRXTxgsah8KFbC1vPazthp7Js+3lQc1GHWKID3ZifmnIDFwGoQHyfbddwnd9T1Kb9r1vTR70W9dN2Ot9j3OwjLt-KBZPgQD50XUDwOoKChVgxBUHQLBcAAYT7eATESeYIVYMKcJpaSeMI+SyVyoTyKKUpqKarTvEYoaqx+Lr4jJzjos-DJ2gUyLqmU4poDEmj6xR7iGgIZo5LpzGGqZxVRnGDT7UJptiY7EzWMSpBzLuR53Js9jfkUvJ8swCRlm2XlUazdViCclF0UxDklb4Alpp8+n-MCsb6KMan1vimX2WS3geT1dKRTFckAoZ9WloK60ybUVV1S1A3SoFcq2cZ4SLBqkOhAWsXaxa-KkCJHqSwAGQNzJOP2jLi7o6kJqzzJ2x69Rs-dPODfqu7ltDrOR0CG0Jy2ssZx+kmYx+Q6HpfE6D2emmIDeoQb0Iu8h+fV9TvHi6r3ez7vuAv6IMgoA)

Comment: Really appreciate your help:D