# typescript limit type to enum only

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code:

```js
enum MY_ENUM {
    A,
    B,
    C
}

type MY_TYPE = {
    field: MY_ENUM
}

// Error: Type '{ field: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'MY_TYPE[]'.
const myArray: MY_TYPE[] = Object.keys(MY_ENUM).map(key => {
    return {
        field: key,  // key is a string, but I want it to be MY_ENUM
    }
})
```

It gives an error on `myArray`, saying string is not assignable to type 'MY_TYPE'.`, so how do I get the enum typed key instead of string? Or in another word, how can I iterate enum, gets the actual enum typed key but not its string representation?

[example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgmgfQKIDkCqMoG8CwAoKQqAQQBp8ioAhcgogYXwF998AXATwAdhZEAVOAAUkUALzYKRAGYBLYABsAJgC4+ydDGas8Ael1QkAJyMB7I2v7deAcixQ5i1VADObI7JABzANxQmANoAujZQsi5QIKZsUACGLi6yXiCxAEYKvGymUJw8UDbwCIIiwTYAdPgAxqYgblAQHMQmsRxqhcVIweJQAPKpAFbAlWxlANbAHC4AFIWoGACUZRCxXFPjHOIAfJJ0hEbAbGBGIDuUlI7KauukhPpQ62ERsa7unl43qWAxAJJQAO6xEAxWQxLJQVK8WaaKSEFh4JjzfBAA)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't Object.keys return a keyof type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript)

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks, the link is helpful but does not give a solution/workaround.

Comment: That's because there isn't one. It's simply not possible to guarantee *compile-time* type safety when you are iterating the properties of an object at *runtime*. You will need to do a runtime check that the object keys are actually members of the enum and cast them appropriately. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66233215/3757232) wrt to narrowing types.