# Optional property does not exist on const object type

Tags: typescript

I have some code like this:

```
const props = {
  a: {
    optional: "foo",
    mandatory: "bar",
  },
  b: {
    mandatory: "blaz",
  },
} as const;

const propsICareAbout: (keyof typeof props)[] = [];

for (const prop of propsICareAbout) {
  if (props[prop].optional) {
    doStuff(props[prop].optional);
  }
}
```

but it gives me this error when I try to access `props[prop].optional`:

```
Property 'optional' does not exist on type '{ readonly mandatory: "blaz"; }'.
```

Notice that `propsICareAbout` is empty. I get this error regardless of if it's empty or if it's `['a', 'b']` or whatever. I tried doing

```
const opt = "optional" in props[prop] ? props[prop].optional : null;
```

but still got the same error.

Comment: The type of `someObj[someKey]` is the union of all the values of that object, e.g. `const foo = { a: 'hi', b: 5 }; let key: keyof typeof foo; const val = foo[key];` then `val` will have type `string | number`. If you have sub-objects with different keys you will have to narrow the type to a *single* member of the union. It is definitely not "ridiculous", and I'm curious how it could be any other way while preserving some modicum of type-safety?

Comment: [In response to now deleted comment] Ok, in that case wonderflame's answer shows how to narrow the type to the object you want. There are [several idioms the compiler will understand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66233215/3757232), including that one.

Comment: It's ridiculous that I can't type `if ("optional" in props[prop]) { props[prop].optional }` I have to do `p = props[prop]; if ("optional" in p) { p.optional }`

Comment: Ok, if that's what you meant I see where you're coming from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a separate variable for `props[prop]` and check with `in` operator:

```
const propsICareAbout: (keyof typeof props)[] = [];
for (const propName of propsICareAbout) {
  const prop = props[propName];
  if ('optional' in prop) {
    prop.optional;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are having a loop on all the keys and its respective properties, you do not have the "optional" key in all sub-objects and hence you are running into the issue.

Please modify your code as mentioned below and check:

```
const props = {
  a: {
    optional: "foo",
    mandatory: "bar",
  },
  b: {
    mandatory: "blaz",
  },
} as const;

const propsICareAbout: (keyof typeof props)[] = ["a"];
for (const prop of propsICareAbout) {
  if ("optional" in props[prop]) {
    doStuff(props[prop].optional);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read all of my question, I already tried a version of this. I tried your exact code code just now, still the same issue.