# Error/response handling types in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a function:

```js
export const createHousehold = async (data: HouseholdFormData): Promise<HouseholdDto | ErrorDto>  => {
  const response: HouseholdDto | ErrorDto = await householdService.createHousehold(data);
  revalidateTag('households');
 
  if (response.error) {
    const errorDto: ErrorDto = {
      status: response.status,
      message: response.message,
      error: response.error,
    };
    return errorDto;
  }
  return response;

};
```

and types:

```js
type HouseholdDto = {
  id: string,
  createdDate: Date,
  modifiedDate: Date,
  name: string,
}


type ErrorDto = {
  status: number,
  error: string,
  message: string,
}
```

What can I do in order to IDE not to shout about the `if (response.error)` and all the properties inside it, so:
[image]

I know it's because I have OR, and the IDE doesn't know what type it will be, but this is why I check the `if (response.error)` to be sure, that the `ErrorDto` is the type of the response.
I would not want to use `HouseholdDto & ErrorDto`, because it would mean, that the `response` is built from two types....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can Typescript not figure out the type in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66233214/why-can-typescript-not-figure-out-the-type-in-my-code)

Comment: `if ('error' in response)`. When you reflect on the object at runtime don't forget that an instance of `HouseholdDto` could have an `error` property added at runtime. And even if *you* know that doesn't happen, the compiler can't *prove* it. The `in` operator is an idiom to opt in to a looser checking in cases like these where you're trying to discriminate variants of a union type.

Comment: thanks, do you mean that assuming the response is of type `HouseholdDto`, that I could "by hand" do something like `response.error = 'test'` and it would be neither typeof `HouseholdDto` nor `ErrorDto`?

Comment: How are we sure that the `in` operator checks if it's typeof `ErrorDto` and nothing has been added to the `HouseholdDto`. Could you provide an example when/how it might happen?

Comment: It would still be of type `HouseholdDto` even with the extra property. Remember TS is structurally typed, as long as it conforms to the interface it is a valid member of the type.

Comment: the `in` operator isn't type safe at all. The point is that *you are querying an object about a single property at runtime and then making assumptions about **all** its other properties* in a way the compiler can't prove. Not just can't prove because of how you wrote it either: it's *logically* impossible to prove at compile time the contents of a runtime object that way. You will have to write *runtime* checks that assert that the thing you want is of the type you think it is. You can turn the dial however you want in terms of how much checking you do.

Comment: If the `in` can't prove the other properties, why TS stops shouting about the `status`, `message` properties and implies that the response is of `ErrorDto` type when I hover on that?

Comment: **Again**, because the TS team decided to allow that specific idiom of using the `in` operator to check for a property access to opt in to looser checking. The `in` operator isn't special, but the compiler pretends that it is for pragmatic reasons.